# Emails not sending from outlook / OWA - Not even hitting the mail queue in exchange

Tags: email, exchange-2010, windows-sbs-2011

We are having an issue this morning where we can receive external emails but cannot send internal or external ones from Outlook or OWA. If I use:

```
Send-MailMessage –From <sender@domain.com> –To <Recipient@domain.com> –Subject “Test #01”-Body “Just a test message.” –SMTPServer <Server-Name> –Credential <domain\user>
```

the email is sent correctly which makes me think there is a connection issue with OWA and Outlook. However, outlook is reporting as Connected with exchange.

I have checked the message tracking in exchange tools and emails sent via outlook and OWA do not appear.

Nothing has changed on the server on the weekend so I don't really know where to start debugging this issue.

We are using Windows SBS 2011. We only have one send connector which isn't using Smart Hosts and is set to use DNS MX records. Use external DNS is not checked and I can ping google.com etc so doesn't appear to be a DNS issue (plus the email sends from the console anyway).

**EDIT** It appears that users using IMAP can send emails correctly, its only ones that rely on the normal exchange connection type that don't work.

**EDIT** Emails from IMAP are hitting the email queue's where as emails from the normal exchange accounts aren't.

**EDIT** It seems that some of the emails we tried to send yesterday sent at about 1am but now it won't work again..

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to get to the bottom of this. I'm not sure how it was working correctly for IMAP but the mail database was corrupt. My past experience of corrupt databases meant the database wouldn't mount but in this case there was no visible evidence there was an issue there so this seems very odd.

Either way, I have repaired all the mailboxes and am in the process of moving them to a new database (just to be safe) and the migrated ones are working correctly.